# SOAP Service return error when used with VS

Tags: c#, soap, joomla, request, virtuemart

a few days ago I start to use a SOAP service for Joomla and VirtueMart connected by a client in C#.
I tried out about a fistful functions and it works fine.
Only one function I've trouble with when I try to use it I get an error.
The developer send me a request that work for him (with my server) but I see only few differents that are not important as I think ...
Maybe somebody can help and show me impoartant differents of the requests that may be a reason for trouble?
This is the working request done with Felx (as URL as I can't insert XML:
[Working Request](http://it-bergmann.de/works.xml)

And this is my request that return a server fault:
[Not working Request](http://it-bergmann.de/error.xml)

Has somebody any idea please?
Fiddler also return an violation but I think that does not matter in this case:
Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 8.958 bytes, but server send 8.959 bytes.

Also a hint how to debug may be useful.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what is the problem. I understand that the SOAP server is on the part? If yes, you need to debug the server to see what he is doing with your request.

Comment: The SOAP reports an error when it'll be called by my VS project. When the request is done by Flex - and in my eyes excact the same - the product will successful add (SOAP handle the request right). I'm a novice with Apache on Linux and have no idea how to debbug - somwthing like a user agent filter to trace action as you suggest.